# Plot hairy ball or circle with arrows inside

Tags: plotting

How can I make a plot of a hairy ball?

[image: Hairy ball]

Comment: Providing a [minimal working example](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2131/7167) will entice other site users to provide assistance.  "Do this for me"-type questions are typically frowned upon.

Comment: Note that the figures in the question, and the one in the answer, are misleading: according to the Hairy Ball Theorem, any continuous vector field on the 2-sphere must vanish at some point!

Answer (score 6):

`VectorPlot` was annoying placing the arrows so I did i my self with graphics primitives

```
Show[Graphics[{Red, 
     Table[Arrow[{(15 - 4 i)/16 #, (12 - 4 i) #/16}], {i, 0, 2, 
       1}]} & /@ CirclePoints[{1, \[Pi]/8}, 16]], Graphics[Circle[]], 
 Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{(15 - 4 3)/16 #, (12.5 - 4 3) #/16}]} & /@ 
   CirclePoints[{1, \[Pi]/8}, 16][[2 ;; ;; 2]]]]
```

[image]

inverting the direction of the arrows is trivial and you should try to do it yourself.

Comment: what about another bottom of ball

Comment: @user45951 did you read the last sentence of my answer?

Comment: thankshttps://skullsinthestars.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/poincaretop.jpg